# Sizing image automatcailly on tablets and ipad

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How can i automatically size my image for better performance on tablets and ipads

i need help with better css to size my image automatically when accessed on tablets and ipads

```
.photo {
 border-radius: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #8e9681;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Search for ```How to make my image responsive?``` and you'll find alot of answers.

Comment: there million answers, but experience not the same, if its beyond your experience its better you ignore it

Comment: If a million didn't solve, add more information of what you have and what you want. More images, working code and what you tried.

Comment: The code that you provided is not complicated at all. Should be findable on Google..
And just as @teefars said include more code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using "%" instead of "px" as it adjusts accordingly to the screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer is this simple

```
max-width: 100%
```

Otherwise please be more clear of what you want, with images and a working code.

Comment: auto can't set customized size of the photo you want. auto is set for 100%

Comment: What do you mean? This is max-width, not width. If max-width is 100%, it will never get bigger than 100% of the width of the parent. Which in turn will always recpect the parent up untill the body and viewport.

Answer (score 0):

put you images inside a img container like

```
  <div class="img-container">
      <img class="img" src="" />
   </div>
```

css

```
 .img-container{
         width:100px;
         height:100px;
         overflow: hidden;
    }

 .img{
       max-width:100%;
      }
```

By doing this you can achieve responsive img

Comment: lets say this is the default size on pc and desktop, then what about all tablets and ipads ?

Comment: setting the width to 100% will always render the img to fit into any screen. You can use media query to target the img-container to reduce the height and width according to the viewport size.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Bootstrap read the Documentation!

Images in Bootstrap are made responsive with `.img-fluid. max-width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` are applied to the image so that it scales with the parent element!

For more Info see: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/